# Ajax image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to make a "change avatar" stuff and it's based not on an uploading photo, but on pictures with outside links(something like that "http://google.com/img.jpg"), so  there form where you can actually can change your avatar and after clicking "Make change" your new avatar is shown.And i'm asking is there any possible way where when you put the link in the form automatically before clicking "make change" to visualize the image.I'm not too much into JavaScript and AJAX, but i'm thinking it will be on the ajax.Any answers are welcomed :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey you need to use `onchange` of file upload to do something for ya.
But i think you should go for this plugin. It works good.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started

Comment: Thanks, i will try and respond later :)